How to Implement Notch in flutter?
I need to like notch type in always show on device top. If i am app background mode or kill mode but This not is always show in top for both android or iOS Device. IS this possible in flutter?
Please review this image
Like this

Yes you can acheive this in Flutter
Check out the repository or this Blog
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dynamic_island_implementation/dynamic_island_manager.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dynamic_island_implementation/dynamic_island_stopwatch_data_model.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const StopwatchApp());
}

class StopwatchApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const StopwatchApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Stopwatch App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const StopWatchScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class StopWatchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const StopWatchScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<StopWatchScreen> createState() => _StopWatchScreenState();
}

class _StopWatchScreenState extends State<StopWatchScreen> {
  int seconds = 0;
  bool isRunning = false;
  Timer? timer;

  /// channel key is used to send data from flutter to swift side over 
  /// a unique bridge (link between flutter & swift) 
  final DynamicIslandManager diManager = DynamicIslandManager(channelKey: 'DI');

  void startTimer() {
    setState(() {
      isRunning = true;
    });

    // invoking startLiveActivity Method
    diManager.startLiveActivity(
      jsonData: DynamicIslandStopwatchDataModel(elapsedSeconds: 0).toJson(),
    );

    timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        seconds++;
      });

      // invoking the updateLiveActivity Method
      diManager.updateLiveActivity(
        jsonData: DynamicIslandStopwatchDataModel(
          elapsedSeconds: seconds,
        ).toJson(),
      );
    });
  }

  void stopTimer() {
    timer?.cancel();
    setState(() {
      seconds = 0;
      isRunning = false;
    });

    // invoking the stopLiveActivity Method
    diManager.stopLiveActivity();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Stopwatch App'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Stopwatch: $seconds seconds',
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: isRunning ? null : startTimer,
                  child: const Text('Start'),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 20),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: isRunning ? stopTimer : null,
                  child: const Text('Stop'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



That's Grate. Thank you so much @Anandh
